# How to monitor Windows Azure Website Endpoint for custom status page

Tags: asp.net, azure

I have a Windows Azure Website hosting my ASP.NET web app, and defined 2 endpoints in my management portal to monitor.  The first is the login page, but the second is a custom "status" page I created that tried to make a connection to databases, web services, etc.  If any of these service connections fail for this page, I want to throw an error code, essentially alerting the management piece that something's not working properly.

At this point, I have set up my alerts in the management portal, and when I was monitoring just the login page, my alerts were sending appropriate error messages.  Now that I added this "status" page, even though the status page isn't working, I still don't get any alerts.

For my status page, if I detect any errors while testing my services, I set the pages Response.Statuscode=400.  I used fiddler to ensure that the 400 code is being set, and have intentionally broke my code a few different ways to ensure the 400 is set for this page, but still nothing.

For endpoint monitoring, can I use this status code, or should I use something else?  Do I need to create alerts in the management portal for specific end points, or are all covered with a management alert?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried throwing Error 500?

Comment: No I haven't, I assumed anything other than 200 would cause an error, but Google failed to give me anything that would assure\deny that fact.  I'll try a 500 error code though, thanks..

Comment: It's reasonable assumption to make, but many monitors ignore error codes in 400's due to 404 not being a real downtime alert.  500 is usually a good catch all for any unexpected errors that most monitors can catch.  Alternatively, if you dont have Azure URL monitoring to work, there are plenty of 3rd party monitors available that specialize in monitoring.

Comment: Thanks, tried setting status code to 500.. but still isn't alerting =-\

Comment: Sorry, their alerting features are still in beta... if you need a little more Azure oompth then just URL monitoring, check out AzureWatch @ http://www.paraleap.com - or you can use something like http://www.pingdom.com for all your URL monitoring needs

Comment: Seen quite a few posts online about pingdom, if necessary I'll check them out, thanks for the time @Igorek

Answer (score 0):

After trying various HTTP Status Codes (400, 404, 500) my alerts weren't kicking off.  In the end I decided to try Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000) (30 seconds).  Not as clean as using a status code, but it's getting the job done.